# Sending html tags with Ajax.Actionlink

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How can I post a partial view contents(contains HTML tags) to a div via `Ajax.ActionLink`

Here is my code:

```
<div id="msgboard" title="Messages" >

</div>

  @Ajax.ActionLink("Read Message", "MsgRead", new{ id = item.id },new    AjaxOptions{HttpMethod="GET",
    UpdateTargetId="msgboard",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess="showdialog"}   )
```

Results: `<b>Great Match</b>`

Expected Result: **Great Match**

Comment: Are the `<b>` tags showing up in your rendered view so that the text does not appear in bold face?

Comment: You get `<b>Great Match<\b>` but you want it to appear as **Great Match**?

Comment: yes you are right Jasen

Comment: I've just tried this and it works. Could you post your partial view and `MsgRead` action?